# Issue with Laravel 4 Routes?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to learn laravel, but I'm running into an issue with routing.

I have the following in my Routes file:

```
Route::get('home', function()
{
        return View::make('home');
});
```

Which works if I type

```
http://localhost/laravel/public/home
```

However, on a another page I have a form, that when submitted should take me to that page like so:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'home')) }}
```

Now this takes me to the correct address, but throws an exception. But, if I reload the page with the same URL then the page loads correctly. So what is the issue here? Is there a problem with the way my form is set up?

Comment: I'm not sure because i don't know laravel much but probably your form sends a post request but you are processing get requests with Route::get can you try Route::any or write another route like Route::post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Route::get is when you want to issue a get request to the page, to get the contents basically.  If you want to post to a page, you need to do, in addition to your Route::get,

```
Route::post
```

Another option that people will tell you is:

```
Route::any
```

but I would advise staying away from this because the logic will probably be different for the two routes.